# Broken external links encoding

Tags: experience-editor, exm

There's an issue in our `EXM` when referring to external links. When we insert these links in `EXM message editor`:

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/23/rock-climbing-cat_n_5380069.html?utm_hp_ref=adventure&hq_e=el&hq_m=4435336&hq_l=15&hq_v=1adccf5361

1. The delivered email then contains only `<a> tag` with no `href`.
2. Also, you get a 500 error in the message editor when trying to edit the link again and you can't edit it anymore.

There's a message in the logs I believe is related to this:

```
> 6688 13:22:30 ERROR Attempted to load invalid xml. Exception:
> System.Xml.XmlException Message: '=' is an unexpected token. The
> expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 94.
```

We found a workaround where we encode the URLs like this:

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/05/23/rock-climbing-cat_n_5380069.html%3Futm_hp_ref%3Dadventure%26hq_e%3Del%26hq_m%3D4435336%26hq_l%3D15%26hq_v%3D1adccf5361

then it works as expected.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you change?  The before and after links are identical

Comment: Just updated - I basically encoded the URL and tried posting that

Comment: Sounds like you've run across a bug - have you opened a ticket with Sitecore?

Comment: yes - but it takes a while to get a response back!

Comment: I have two Sitecore Support Tickets about this very thing logged.  Still waiting for response. Once I receive will update with an answer.

Comment: This is a known platform bug.It's fixed in 8.2, but you'll have to wait for the release of EXM 3.4 to use EXM with 8.2

Answer (score 4):

This bug is referenced in the knowledge base as Reference number: 88491.

Specifically, it patches the majority of the `<sitecore.experienceeditor.speak.requests>` pipeline and takes care to ensure that requests to the SPEAK which are generally handled over AJAX calls are properly formatted.

It should be noted that this is an issue specifically with Sitecore `Experience Editor` and NOT `EXM` specifically.  However, it's easy to blame `EXM` due to the tight integration that `Experience Editor` has inside of the `Email eXperience Manager`

The fix itself has been fixed in **Sitecore 8.2**, however **EXM 3.4** (which supports Sitecore 8.2) isn't released yet of the writing of this response.

> There is ***NOT*** an actual kb.sitecore.net article on this issue.

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic, but you're not entirely correct. This is an issue in the Experience Editor, and as such applies to all users of Experience Editor, not only EXM. It's true it's fixed in 8.2 though.

Comment: Not being pedantic. You're right, I will update the response.  It's so easy to confuse the two, since Experience Editor tightly integrates into EXM.